# Unable to resolve module _stream_writable from firebase-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-admin

I tried clean and install node_modules and delete cache but don't change error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the commands you have tried and give more details about your setup ?

Comment: I add a picture but Its not looking, can you click "this Error"  text.

Comment: ok, I give more details :) I use npm install --save firebase-admin and I import with #import Admin from 'firebase-admin' to project but I have error

Comment: You should be using `import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'`. Also, it looks like you are using React Native (or at least some other platform for building iOS apps). The Admin SDKs are intended for server environments, not end-user devices. You should use the regular firebase node module for that.

Comment: @jacobawenger what about if the app needs to do admin stuff? i also have the same problem in an app that also an admin can login and manage stuff.